# How to create channel using fabric-client sdk in hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've been working on building an api for hyperledger fabric network that is to be used in one of our projects. The major issue is that there is absolutely ridiculous documentation available for the same . The documentation does not contain any examples and that has made it hell for me.
This is the code I have figured out , I'm able to make a connection to the network but my method fails with 'parameter error'.

Can someone please explain how would one approach such a problem . Also are there any other ways to acheive this . I have an another approach which requires running a kubernetes job that runs a script to create a new channel and its artifacts. But I think the sdk approach would be a cleaner one.

```
const getchannels = async () => {
    
    console.log("Here")
    
    try {
        
        const ccp = buildCCPOrg1();

    // build an instance of the fabric ca services client based on
    // the information in the network configuration
    const caClient = buildCAClient(
      FabricCAServices,
      ccp,
      "ca.org1.example.com"
    );

    // setup the wallet to hold the credentials of the application user
    const wallet = await buildWallet(Wallets, walletPath);

    // in a real application this would be done on an administrative flow, and only once
    await enrollAdmin(caClient, wallet, mspOrg1);
    
        const client = new Client('admin');
        // const identity = org1UserId;
        
        const identity = await wallet.get(org1UserId);
        
        console.log(identity);
        
        
        
        // await client.setUserContext('admin');
        await client.setUserContext(org1UserId, true);
        
        await client.loadFromConfig(ccp);
        
        const peer = new Client.Peer("grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7051");
        
        const channel = await client.newChannel("newchannel");
        
        channel.addPeer(peer);
        
        const response = await client.queryChannels(peer);
        
        console.log("Result : \n");

        console.log(response);
    
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

//Build CCP
exports.buildCCPOrg1 = () => {
    // load the common connection configuration file
    const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test-network', 'organizations', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'connection-org1.json');
    const fileExists = fs.existsSync(ccpPath);
    if (!fileExists) {
        throw new Error(`no such file or directory: ${ccpPath}`);
    }
    const contents = fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8');

    // build a JSON object from the file contents
    const ccp = JSON.parse(contents);

    console.log(`Loaded the network configuration located at ${ccpPath}`);
    return ccp;
};
```

This is the code for the query.

Error :

```
Error: Missing parameter. Must have a username.
    at Client._setUserFromConfig (/home/haaris/go/src/github.com/haariskhatri/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1400:10)
    at Client.setUserContext (/home/haaris/go/src/github.com/haariskhatri/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1535:15)
    at getchannels (/home/haaris/go/src/github.com/haariskhatri/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript/app.js:124:16)
    at async /home/haaris/go/src/github.com/haariskhatri/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript/app.js:89:2
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use the **fabric-client** API for Hyperledger Fabric v1.4. The API documentation you are missing is [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/index.html).

Please note that neither Fabric v1.4 or the **fabric-client** API are supported anymore. With Fabric v2.2, **fabric-client** was entirely replaced by **fabric-common**, although this was designed purely as a low-level implementation to support the high-level [**fabric-network**](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/index.html) API, which is the recommended API for building client applications for both Fabric v1.4 and v2.2. From Fabric v2.4 onwards (including the current v2.5 long-term support release), the *only* supported API for client application development is the [Fabric Gateway client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/).

From Fabric v2.2, the client APIs intentionally do not support administrative operations, such as channel creation. For admin tasks, there are three primary approaches that can be used:

1. The Fabric [CLI commands](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/command_ref.html). This is the approached used to configure the [test-network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network) used in the Fabric samples.
2. The [Fabric Admin SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-admin-sdk). At the time of writing the primary Golang implementation is close to but not quite at stable v1.0 release level. The repository also contains a Node.js admin API (based on code developed [here](https://github.com/davidkhala/fabric-common/tree/master/nodejs/admin)), but it likely is not yet in a stable, supported state.
3. If deploying to Kubernetes, use a Kubernetes operator designed for managing Fabric. Two alternatives that I know of are [Hyperledger Fabric Operator](https://hyperledger.github.io/bevel-operator-fabric/) and [fabric-operator](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/fabric-operator).